# Avoid duplicating namespaces during xml serialization using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

The following code

```
var ns1 = 'hello:world1',
    doc = document.implementation.createDocument('nsdoc', 'doc', null),
    outer = doc.createElement('outer'),
    s = new XMLSerializer(),
    elm;

outer.setAttribute('xmlns:ns1', ns1);
elm = doc.createElementNS(ns1, 'Inner');

outer.appendChild(elm);

console.log(s.serializeToString(outer));
```

outputs the following xml document in chrome and firefox.

```
<outer xmlns:ns1="hello:world1">
  <Inner xmlns="hello:world1"/>
</outer>
```

While this is technically still valid, is there a way to remove the duplicate ns declaration or is there a better api to be using to setup namespaces on a parent node for use in children? Eg, it would be preferred for the document to look as follows:

```
<outer xmlns:ns1="hello:world1">
  <ns1:Inner/>
</outer>
```

Comment: worst case:  s.serializeToString(outer).split('xmlns="hello:world1"').join('')

Comment: @dandavis that wont work as then the node is missing the 'ns1:' prefix that indicates a different namespace for that node.

Comment: if both are using ns1, there's no need for the inner tag to be namespaced. also, you cannot set a namespace internal attrib like that, use setAttributeNS and createElementNS for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! In this case the namespaces are different -- so it does matter (outer's is not shown in the example tho). As for setAttributeNS over setAttribute: setAttributeNS will cause an error when the attribute name is 'xmlns:ns1' ("NamespaceError: DOM Exception 14"). This error may actually be related to why the browser is duplicating the namespaces, but that is also part of the rational for me posting the question ... is there another API i should be using to prevent duplicate namespace declaration and to move the definition to a higher shared node like in my last xml snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to gain much better control over how namespaces are serialized via the use of DOMParser and a little bit of uncomfortable handwritten XML (but only for the root nodes). The following javascript did this:

```
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    s = new XMLSerializer(),
    dom1 = parser.parseFromString('<doc xmlns="one"></doc>', 'text/xml'),
    dom2 = parser.parseFromString('<outer xmlns="one" xmlns:ns3="hello-world"></outer>', 'text/xml'),
    myElm = dom2.createElementNS('hello-world', 'ns3:Inner');

dom2.documentElement.appendChild(myElm);
dom2.documentElement.attributes.removeNamedItem('xmlns');
dom1.documentElement.appendChild(dom2.documentElement);
console.log(s.serializeToString(dom1));
```

This outputs the following xml in Chrome (26.0 on mac), Firefox (21.0 on mac) and Opera (12.15 on mac -- though Opera also includes xml declaration which is ok for my needs)

```
<doc xmlns="one">
  <outer xmlns:ns3="hello-world">
    <ns3:Inner/>
  </outer>
</doc>
```